# What is the best way to protect my program from cracking?

Tags: vb.net, security, drm

I've written a VB program. How do I add anti-tamper code so people can't crack it?

Comment: Infinity Ward (Call of Duty Modern Warfare 2) wants to know too.. - http://www.google.com.my/search?q=the+most+pirated+game

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the easiest thing to do is implement a [licensing system](http://www.licensingdotnet.com/)

With regards to securing the code, one thing you can do is [obfuscate](http://www.preemptive.com/products/dotfuscator/overview)

Comment: @Michael Mrozek's edit has rendered my answer slightly invalid.

Comment: Oh, maybe I misunderstood what he was asking -- feel free to edit it if so

Comment: Did you search the site before posting? This one comes up regulalry and the acceptaed answer is almost always "you can't, you can only make it more difficult"

Comment: I never said it was foolproof.  I just know it "helps"

Answer (score 1):

Crack it,  as in pirate your software?  You'll never be able to stop piracy.    [You can try using a cd key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002067/how-are-cd-keys-generated) and a [free obfuscater](http://www.top4download.com/free-vb-net-obfuscator/),  but thats the best you can do.  I wouldn't pay for an obfuscater,  even if you paid $5 you probably won't see a return on investment.