# Product activation with public key certificate

Tags: c#, security, windows-7, certificate, activation

I need some ideas how to create a activation algorithm. For example i have demo certificate. Providing that the application runs in demo mode. When full version certificate is provided then application runs in full mode.
Is it even possible and how would be a good way creating this system?

One simple was i was thinking would be just have a 2 encrypted strings, now when the decryption is succsessful with the demo public key certificate then the application will run in demo mode and etc..

Comment: Reminds me of one of my answers to a previous question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002067/how-are-software-license-keys-generated/3081342#3081342

Comment: So what's the use case? What kind of software is it protecting, what kind of volume, what price?

Comment: @jamie, see the comment under your answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could do something like:

1. Generate public/private key pair
2. As owner of private key, you can sign those "activation certificates" (called AC from now on)
3. In your app, with public key, you can check if the sign is correct

As Overbose mentioned -- you can't prevent reverse engineering. In general someone could take functionality and put it in his/hers own app and thus eliminate any possible activation algorithm. So you can only assume (or make) this is hard enough not to be worth the effort (this is the same as for cryptography -- when you make the cost of breaking the message greater then the profit of gaining it you can say it is well secured).

So you could:

1. Make executable self-verifying (signed by you, self-checking based on hard-coded public key (one thing: you must skip this value when self-checking)).
2. Do some tricks with pointers (point to the activation function, go to 7th bit and change value of it for something based on value of another pointer; in some weird places change hard-coded values to those based on occurrence of some bits in other places of the code; generally -- make it more difficult to break than by simply changing bits in executable with hex editor)
3. Try to make some protocol that your server would use to ask questions about the app ("gimme the value of 293 byte of yourself") and check answers.
4. Use imagination and think of some weird self-checking method nobody used before :)

As mentioned -- none of this is secure from cutting the authentication part off. But nothing is and this could make it harder for crackers.

Answer (score 5):

Background: I've deployed an activation based system built on top of a third-party license system, i.e. server, database, e-commerce integrations. I've also separately written a C# activation system using RSA keys, but never deployed it.

Product *Activation* commonly means that the software must be activated on a given machine. I assume that's what you mean. If all you want to do is have two strings that mean "demo" and "purchased", then they will be decrypted and distributed within hours (assuming your product is valuable). There is just no point.

So. assuming you want "activation", then when the user purchases your software, the following process needs to happen:

1. Order-fulfillment software tells Server to generate "Purchase Key" and send to user
2. User enters "Purchase Key" into software
3. Software sends Purchase Key and unique Machine ID to server.
4. Server combines Purchase Key and Machine ID into a string and signs it with its certificate and returns it to user.
5. Software checks that signature is valid using Servers public key.
6. Software could check in lots of places: loading the sig in lots of places, checking it in others.

When generating Purchase Keys, the server can store not only what produce was purchased, but what level of product. You can also have "free" products that are time limited, so the user can try the full version of the software for 30 days.

You are using C#, so make sure you obfuscate the binaries, using dotfuscator or equivalent. However, even with that there is nothing you can do against a determined hacker. Your goal, I assume, is to force non-paying users to either be hackers themselves, or to have to risk using a cracked version: kids wont care, corporations might. YMMV.

The code that does the checking needs to be in every assembly that needs protecting, otherwise an attacker can trivially remove protection by replacing the assembly that does the checking. Cut and paste the code if you have to.

Or just buy something.

Another option is to have the server pre-generate "Purchase Keys" and give them to the Order fulfillment service, but then you dont get to link the key to the customers details (at least not until they register). Better to have the ecommerce server hit your server when a purchase has been made, and have your server send it out.

The hard part isn't so much the generation of activation keys as it is the creation of the server, database, and the integration with e-commerce software, and most of all, human issues: do you allow unlimited installs per Purchase Key? Only 1? If only 1 then you have to have customer-support and a way to allow a user to install it on a new machine. That's just one issue. All sorts of fun.

Comment: This is a good answere but creating a server based activation is just not the option for me. I should of mentioned that in my original post...

Comment: Well in that case, expect a key to get leaked. If that's a problem, then you can monitor the warez sites and include a list of blocked keys in each new version of the software. Using pubkey encryption is good because it means that attackers can't create keygen software (unless they hack your computer and get the key, in which case all bets are off). On that note, if you want to go crazy you could use a verified certificate that allows revocation.

Comment: Just to get some more ideas i mention here that this application wouldn't be for public use, its is used in very tight group of companies, anybody else just wont have anything to do with it.

Comment: Have you checked that they'll go with a custom solution? We had a couple of clients (Fortune 50) who would require floating FlexLM licenses. If you didn't have that, their IT guys wouldn't support it, so departments couldn't buy it.

Comment: Yes, im sure they will accept any solution we are going to implement. And more to mention, in the environment the application is used there is no internet connection so activation using server is not possible..

Answer (score 3):

This guy wrote [a blog post](http://www.zabkat.com/blog/27Jun10-openssl-keygen.htm) about a similar idea, explaining what he did with their own commercial software. Also wrote [a list of recommendations](http://www.zabkat.com/blog/30Jul11-dummy-software-cracks.htm) about the most obvious cracking techniques. Hope it helps.

Comment: He didn't mention the attack where you just replace the public key.  Maybe he didn't mention it because its trivial to carry out and it completely breaks this approach.

Answer (score 1):

> One simple was i was thinking would be just have a 2 encrypted
>   strings, now when the decryption is succsessful with the demo public
>   key certificate then the application will run in demo mode and etc..

Could be a simple solution. But this way you won't prevent someone to reverse engineer your binaries and make the execution jump to the correct line. Everyone has your program, has a complete version of it, so it's only a matter of find how to break this simple mechanism.

Maybe a better solution is encrypt a part of the binaries needed to use the full application version, instead of a simple string. This way to execute the application complete version someone need to decrypt those binaries in order to execute them.

Please take in consideration that even that solution isn't enough. There are other problems with that:

1. Does all the version of your tool will share the same encryption key? Breaking one of them for breaking all..
2. Even if you use a different key for each binary application released, does the encrypted binary are identical? Once cracked one, you can reuse the unencrypted binaries for all distributed applications.

How to solve these problems? There's no simple solution. Most of the more important commercial software with even sophisticated protection systems are broken just few hours or days after they have been released.

Comment: Yes, you are right and i know about this. The question is about the activation algorithm/system not about preventing it to be reverse engineered.

Answer (score 1):

Product activation is not a problem that asymmetric cryptography can solve.  Asymmetric cryptography is about keeping secrets from your adversary.  The problem is that you can't keep a secret that is stored on you're adversaries machine,  that would be [security though obscurity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity).

[The correct way to do product activation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002067/how-are-software-license-keys-generated/3050217#3050217).   Is to generate a [Cryptographic Nonce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce) that is stored in a database on your server.  You give this Nonce to the customer when they buy the product,  and then they activate it online.   This activation process could download new material,  which would make it more difficult for the attacker to [modify the copy they have](http://www.hex-rays.com/idapro/) to "unlock" new features.

But even with DRM systems that [require you to be online](http://www.pcgamer.com/2011/08/19/from-dust-drm-requires-internet-connection-to-launch-players-experiencing-bugs-and-crashes/) while using the product.  Like the ones found in new games like "From Dust" are [still broken](http://thepiratebay.org/search/from%20dust/0/99/0) within hours of their release.

Comment: You're right if someone is going to modify your binaries (although downloaded content can pretty easily be captured, so while 1 license might be purchased, many more could be stolen). If someone isn't going to modify your binaries using asymmetric cryptography to sign and verify product licenses is pretty bullet proof (as long as your private key, which is NOT distributed, remains secret)

Comment: @userx If they aren't going to crack your software then no one cares about it and there for its not worth anything.  But how about this,  try and pirate Software as a Service (SaaS).  Cracking WoW isn't so easy,  although even pirated servers have been created.

Comment: Sorry, but I still fail to see your point. Asymmetric encryption has a place in product activations and licensing. Does it protect against all methods of piracy, no. Does it allow you to verify that a license is from a given source, yes. All product activation is security through obscurity. I disagree with the blanket statement that if "no one is cracking your software then no one cares". Cracking is very industry specific. Gaming, yes it's a problem. Enterprise web load balancing, not so much.

Comment: @userx let me be clear this is in no way shape or form a secure system.

Comment: You claim that the secret is "stored on your adversaries machine", but the private key (what you use to sign the license) remains internal. The public key (what you use to verify the license) is what is exposed. Sure, if you cracked the software & replaced the public cert internally with a different one, you're right. But this is no different than if someone cracked your binary & simply bypassed your licensing mechanism. The question isn't about protecting SaaS or token based DRM; it's about product activation. How does activating a product with a signed key fail to do this reasonably?

Comment: @userx  The problem is that a business model is relying upon something that is completely and totally impossible to solve.   If you think you have a solution you are a **fool**.

Comment: I don't think I was proposing an absolute solution... In fact quite the opposite of that, simply disagreeing with your post because asymmetric cryptography CAN have a place in piracy prevention... Just because it's a hard problem to solve doesn't make it futile. It's a delicate balance between attempted IP protection level and user convenience. Asymmetric encryption CAN walk that line nicely, if implemented properly.

Comment: @userx  it will take 3-5 minutes to break your solution.

Comment: Without modifying the binaries, I fail to see how. If you could determine the private key of a 1024-bit RSA cert in 3-5 mins, SSL wouldn't be safe either. Care to give an example? Yes, I realize that you could simply swap out the public key used internally. I'm not sure how this is much different than simply modifying a binary to skip the license checking all together (which renders any anti-piracy method useless). I guess you might replace the RSA implementation on your local machine to always use a different public key (at the risk of breaking everything else that uses RSA on that machine).

Comment: @userx  Okay so I'm going to open this beer bottle without the bottle opener in my hand.  This is not a realistic threat model.  Cheers.

Comment: I just fail to see how presuming that someone not finding (and overriding) your nonce based proposal is somehow better than presuming that someone won't find (and replace) your public key. Both are threats and seem to me to be on a similar scale (reverse engineering and binary patching), but under normal operation, one involves a server setup and an internet connection, the other requires an RSA implementation. If there is something here I'm missing, I'd love to learn more on the topic.

Answer (score 0):

One of the benefits of public key encryption is that you can [verify the origin](http://xheo.com/docs/dlxl/5/html/developers%20guide/licensing%20basics/keys%20and%20signatures.html) of a given piece of data. So if you store the public key in your assembly, then sign a given piece of data (say an authorization code or serial number) your assembly can verifiably determine that you were the one that created that data - and not a hacker. The actual data itself isn't all that important - it can be a simple pass/fail value.

This is actually pretty easy to do with .NET. You can use an x509 certificates or like we use in [DeployLX Licensing](http://xheo.com/products/copy-protection) the [RSACryptoServiceProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider.aspx).

I would highly recommend buying a commercial product (doesn't really matter which one, though DeployLX is excellent) and not doing this yourself for 2 reasons

1. Even if you're a great developer, you'll probably get it wrong the first time. And any savings you might have enjoyed by rolling your own will be lost to recovering from that mistake.
2. You'll spend far more time working on your own system - time that you should spend making your product great.

The second phase in protecting the software is to make sure that it runs the way you created it - and hasn't been modified by a hacker. It really doesn't matter what encryption you use if hackers can check `if( licensed )` to `if( true )`.

Answer (score -2):

You can use [AsProtect](http://www.aspack.com/asprotect.html) to solve this problem. This is good staring point.