# Verifying product key

Tags: java, python, security

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How are Software License Keys generated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002067/how-are-software-license-keys-generated)

How do software programs verify the product key offline? Is there already a list of possible keys in the db, or does the program decode the input key in some way? If the latter, how is the decoding done?

Comment: A good example of this is how validation is performed on Australian Business Numbers (http://www.ato.gov.au/businesses/content.aspx?doc=/content/13187.htm&pc=001/003/021/002/001&mnu=610&mfp=001/003&st=&cy=1), and Credit Card Numbers (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm).

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are multitudes of algorithms that can be used to encode/decode product keys (using matricies etc.), but one of the more common methods is by use of a program called Keygen. For more information on Keygen, check out [this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keygen).