# Random numbers with rand() and one seed

Tags: php

I have to generate a large number of unique keys. One key should consist of 16 digits. I came up with the following code:

```
function make_seed()
{
    list($usec, $sec) = explode(' ', microtime());
    return (float) $sec + ((float) $usec * 100000);
}
function generate_4_digits(){
    $randval = rand(100, 9999);
    if($randval < 1000){
        $randval = '0'.$randval;
    }
    return (string)$randval;
}
function generate_cdkey(){
    return generate_4_digits() . '-' . generate_4_digits() . '-' . generate_4_digits() . '-' . generate_4_digits();
}


srand(make_seed());
echo generate_cdkey();
```

The result was quite promising, `6114-0461-7825-1604`.
Then I decided to generate 10 000 keys and see how many duplicates I get:

```
srand(make_seed());
$keys = array();
$duplicates = array();
for($i = 0; $i < 10000; $i++){
    $new_key = generate_cdkey();
    if(in_array($new_key, $keys)){
        $duplicates[] = $new_key;
    }
    $keys[] = $new_key;
}
$keys_length = count($keys);
var_dump($duplicates);
echo '<pre>';
for($i = 0; $i < $keys_length; $i++){
    echo $keys[$i] . "\n";
}
echo '</pre>';
```

On first run I got `1807` duplicates which was quite disappointing. But for my great surprise on each following run I get the same number of duplicates!? When I looked closely at the generated keys, I realized the last `1807` keys were exactly the same as the first ones. So I can generate `8193` without a single duplicate?! This is so close to 2^13?! Can we conclude `rand()` is suited to generate maz 2^13 unique numbers? But why?

I changed the code to use `mt_rand()` and I get no duplicates even when generating 50 000 keys.

Comment: What's a cd key? And how about just using an existing UUID / GUID generator?

Comment: @Evert, I want to generate a key with 16 digits. 32 hex digits is quite large for my needs.

Comment: Tested the code, no duplicates here .. tested on PHP 5.3.6

Comment: @dbf, hm, very strange. Let me try it on codepad.org

Comment: @dbf, I get timeouts on codepad.org. I am on Windows, PHP 5.3.8

Comment: $randval = rand(100, 9999);
    if($randval < 1000){
        $randval = '0'.$randval;
    }
could be condensed to this:
$randval = sprintf("%04d", rand(100, 9999));

Comment: See if using `mt_rand` instead of `rand` makes any difference?  Also, see this answer [How are software license keys generated?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002067/how-are-software-license-keys-generated)

Comment: @iandouglas, that looks much better. Thanks.

Comment: Any particular reason you're using just decimal numbers? You could include hex values (A-F) and expand each group of 4 as high as 65535 giving you way more options. $randval = sprintf("%04X", rand(256,65535)); Hex would also avoid ambiguity of 1's vs I's, 0's vs O's of using the entire alphabet. Even if you don't theoretically need that many, it might still help your overlap problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably more what you're looking for. [openssl_random_pseudo_bytes ( int $length [, bool &$crypto_strong ] )](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-random-pseudo-bytes.php)

Comment: To explain my thought process, you could specify a length of 8 (16 characters I think in bytes) and then add a '-' in every 4 characters.

Answer (score 1):

Throw some uniquid() in there.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php

Comment: Thanks but I want to generate 16 digits key.

Comment: That's why I was like "throw in" instead of "just use". `function getFourDigits() { return substr(uniquid(), 0, 4) }` ... something like that

Comment: uniqid() is not suited for my needs. It returns letters and digits.

Comment: Really? I didn't know that, sorry. Wrap a `preg_replace('/\D/', '', $uniquid())` around it then. It removes all non-digit characters.

Answer (score 0):

This might be something to do with the behaviour of srand. When checking for duplicates you are only running srand once for all 10000 keys. Perhaps srand only produces enough for ~2^13 keys? What PHP version are you using? Since 4.2.0 srand isn't needed any more, but perhaps in if you call it anyway it stops doing it automatically for the rest of the script.