# Having trouble with mac address, if the user changes internet connection

Tags: c#

I have an application which is working with generated licence (Mac-Id and some other hardware adresses). Everything works fine but if the user changes the internet connection from cable internet to Wlan connection or vice versa it gives a licence error. I know mac address will be changed if the internet connection is changed.

Is there a known solution ?

Any idea for this problem would be appreciated.

Comment: For example by not using the MAC address of the active adapter, but concatenating all MAC address of all adapters on the system?

Comment: @CodeCaster - and then they plug in a 3G dongle, or unplug it, and suddenly their license is invalid again. Or they connect a VPN. The answer is surprisingly simpler than this - stop using the MAC address at all. It's not a good proxy for "the machine"

Answer (score 2):

Using mac address is not a good idea cause users can change it manually. In your case Wireless NIC and Ethernet NIC has two different MAC addresses, So you should remember which one you used or not use MAC address at all.

Comment: If your answer was just the last part of the last sentence, I'd +1 it. MAC addresses are just not a good proxy for machine identity.

Comment: I have mentioned it in very first sentence of my answer. However, the question here is not to advice best practice but how to handle the situation described.

Comment: It's not just users changing them manually that can cause MAC addresses to disappear or appear, and whichever one the code "remembers" as having selected can easily be one that disappears.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I just thought about security aspect of it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could enumerate all MAC address instead of using the MAC address of the active connection.

Also, this large post about [How are Software License Keys generated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002067/how-are-software-license-keys-generated) is quite worth a look.