# Is it possible to decompile the whole .NET application?

Tags: c#, reflection, reverse-engineering, decompiling

I know that .NET apps are difficult to protect. I use RedGate Reflector and know that generally speaking you can get source code from many .NET dlls.

however my question is - is it actually feasible to decompile the whole application?

I mean - create a *workable VS solution* so the pirate can just press F5 and get the exactly same result as if the author on his machine?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reflector have few plugins that allows to dump assembly into code:

http://www.denisbauer.com/home/reflectorfiledisassembler

http://filegenreflector.codeplex.com/

But I'm not sure that can create a project file.

Answer (score 1):

For a small application, it is both possible AND feasible. You have to decompile the classes one by one and copy/paste the code into Visual Studio.

For a large application, while possible, it's not really feasible since the copy/paste process becomes extremely tedious.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what kind of code you are writing.   If you use a lot of the new features in C# 3 and above like lambda expressions, automatic properties, and yield, the decompiled source code is not runnable and requires quite a bit of work to get it to compile.

Even without those features though, I have usually experienced at least **some** problems compiling the decompiled source code of a full winforms application.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's anything that fully automates this for an app made up of multiple assemblies, but I can say that it's really not that hard to stitch the pieces together into a solution yourself.  Perhaps a bit tedious for a large app, but if you *really* want to it's certainly doable.

Fortunately, I [don't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364148/is-there-any-good-method-to-encrypt-the-c-desktop-application/2364250#2364250) [worry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338337/how-does-a-net-exe-work/2338556#2338556) [about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/651291/securing-a-net-application/651375#651375) [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/506282/protect-net-code-from-reverse-engineering/651375#651375) [much](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2478230/how-can-i-protect-my-net-assemblies-from-decompilation/2478504#2478504).

Answer (score 1):

There are many obfuscators these days that protect your .NET applications from decompilation. One such obfuscator is http://www.red-gate.com/products/smartassembly/index.htm . They try to make your well structured .NET IL code into spegatti code (which still works) that decompilers cannot generate original code. It's not like 100% sure piraters cannot get the recompilable code but it will not be easy for them to decompile when using obfuscator.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you simply Export from Reflector and get a complete runnable Project for your assembly.
I've done it a couple of times.
Usually, I have to migrate the project to my version of VS and some times it requires some minor fixes, but in general it works.